# What's the best way to perform very large regex operations?

Tags: regex, powershell, command-line

I have a text file that is over 2 million lines long, and I'm trying to remove all of the newline characters, putting all the text on a single line.

I'm also removing any extra whitespace characters at the same time.

**Attempt #1:** I tried using Visual Studio 2017, which simply chokes and crashes on the workload.
`Find and replace "\s+" with " "`

**Attempt #2:** I tried using PowerShell, which completed successfully, and combined all consecutive whitespace characters into a single space character, but doesn't remove any newline characters for some reason.
`(Get-Content -path "Input.txt") -replace "\n", " " -replace "\r", " " -replace "\s+", " " | Out-File "Output.txt"`

Obviously Visual Studio is out of the question, since it can't handle the job.

But why is PowerShell removing extra whitespace correctly, but not line breaks?
Am I doing something incorrectly?

Or is there a better tool for the job?

Comment: If you are using `Get-Content`, the default is to return an array with each line being an indexed element in the array. If you want to replace newline characters that way, you need to use `Get-Content -Raw` which will output the text as is. An alternative is to just join the array elements with a space like `(Get-Content Input.txt) -join " "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be the best (and best performing) solution, is to add `-raw` as suggested in the comments.
The command executes in seconds, rather than minutes.

```
(Get-Content -raw -path "Input.txt") -replace "\s+", " " | Out-File "Output.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The task you are requesting is actually quite difficult for many tools that are line based, as they want to package the output line in memory before emitting it. You are asking them to package the whole file into 1 line, which is impractical for a large file.

As you have seen, some tools don't even consider replacing newlines at all, so that they minimise this risk.

One hack is to specify an option to tell the tool to use another character as the newline or record separator, something that you don't want to change that occurs reasonably frequently, so the "lines" are not too big. Space may be a good candidate.

With `sed` and `awk` this is relatively easy, and I'm sure someone will come along in a moment with an exact command-line for you :-).

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  I'm only doing one line at a time.  And adding a space at the end of each line '$'.

```
Get-Content Input.txt | foreach { $_ -replace '\s+',' ' -replace '$',' ' } | 
  set-content -nonewline Output.txt
```